# FireStore Documents only showing sometimes

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Fetching data from my FireStore DB is unreliable and it worsens after adding a new feature that uses the first date fetch to do some more data fetchs

I've my user songs (which are document ids to match the data)

[image]To

[image]

```kotlin
//To get user data 
suspend fun getAllUserPlaylists():List<Playlists>
        = try{  FS_USER.get().await().toObjects(Playlists::class.java) }
          catch (e:Exception){ emptyList() /*getAllUserPlaylists()*/ }

//Function to call above funcion
val allUserPlaylist =  GlobalScope.launch { vm.allUserPlaylists. postValue(MusicDB(). getAllUserPlaylists()) }


runBlocking {
            //wait for data fetch to finish
            allUserPlaylist.join()
            Log.i("WORKS","${vm.allUserPlaylists.value}")

            //Match ids with song data
            vm.allUserPlaylists.value?.forEach {
                val q = arrayListOf<Song>()
                it.songsIDs.forEach { it2 ->
                    val t = FS_ALL_SONGS.document(it2).get().await().toObject(Song::class.java)
                    if (t != null) {
                        q.add(t)
                    }
                }
                //Insert
                val vmT = vm.allUserPlaylists.value!!
                vmT[vmT.indexOf(it)].songs = q
                vm.allUserPlaylists.postValue(vmT)
            }
  }
```

```kotlin
data class Song(val mediaID: String = "", val title: String = "",
                val artist: String = "", val songURL: String = "",
                val imgURL: String = "", val album: String = "")
data class Playlists(val name:String= "", val mainArtists: String = "",
                     var songs:ArrayList<Song> = arrayListOf(),
                     val songsIDs:ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf(),
                     val imgURL:String = "",var pinned:Boolean = false)
```

What i dont get why is it so unreliable.In theory it should work but only does (10% of the time) after clearing all app data and cache.I simpliy add documents to a list with using their doc ids and display it using a recycler view that updates on value change.

So any sort of help is appreicated

**Edited** : My code doesn't provide any visible errors (to me) however even though *getAllUsersPlaylists* function returns valid results(doc IDs) which I've confirmed  by logging.

Code snippet to *match doc IDs with song data* doesn't give expected results(also checked by logging).It doesn't match the Doc Ids with data so doesn't return song data that I've referred using its doc IDs.
And this data is later shown to the user using a recycler view which auto updates ui

*Song IDs refer to the doc IDs for song data*

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I've edited my question as per you've asked

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. If you say that "getAllUsersPlaylists function returns valid results", then what's the issue?

Comment: it returns list of playlists (refer to the data classes above) and each playlist has song Ids( they refer to (song data in child("songs/songID") so I need to get that data from the other collection (hence 'match data') and perform/display actions accordingly. So I'm asking for any help to find out why doesn't my code perform its function .  **Sorry for the poorly explained question, I'm gonna try to explain it ask well as possible**